# Batch files with findstr and rename

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am quite new at this, but anyway I try.
How do I code a batch file to find a file containing a specific word an then rename that file?
I use findstr, and it find the file, but how do i catch the ouput from this, and use the output to rename the file or those files?

i hope that someone Can help me.
Thank you
Steffen

Answer (score 1):

Primitively,

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=u:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /m /L /c:"find me" "%sourcedir%\*.*"') DO (
 ECHO(REN "%%a" "destinationname"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The game however is in what you haven't told us - **how** you want to rename the file, since you can only have one file with any particular name in a directory.

Comment: Hi Magoo
Now it works..... You have a "(" to much and I have chosen to move the files instead of rename them.
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\mid"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /M /L /I /c:"milwaukee" "%sourcedir%\*.*"') DO (
 move "%%a" "c:\mid\mid2")

GOTO :EOF

Comment: Ah - you mean the `(` in `echo(` ? Um, no - that's actually not an error. There's a difference between `echo %something` and `echo(%something%`. If `something` is empty, the first will show the `echo` status (ON or OFF) but the second will quietly show, well, nothing... Good move to er, move the file. Sensible programmed renaming can be a gymnastic nightmare.